# ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() can the completionPortThreads number be set to 0?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I want to set the minimum number of threads. I knoe the number of workerThreads I need but about the completionPortThreads what should be it's size (by dafault it is equal to the number of processors). can I set it to 0 or is it risky? when will it be used?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the **minimum** number of threads to 0 if you like. This means that the OS will have to start new threads when they are required, and stop them again when they are not, and may result in fewer tasks running concurrently, both of which will have a performance impact.

You cannot set the **maximum** number to less than the number of processors.